# Custom AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: php, mysql

I have in a MYSQL db two tables that are linked:

- ADMIN

  `id - name - company`

Each admin adds several values ​​in the table docs:

- DOCS

  `id_doc - id_admin_doc - doc - value`

The `id_admin_doc` column is a foreign key of the `admin` table, what I want is exactly that with each new record with msm `id_admim_doc` a `doc` with `AUTO_INCREMENTE` be added like this: `doc_1`,  `doc_2` ...

But each list of each `admin` must be filled in independently, that is, `admin` 1 has `doc_1`, `doc_2` ... And in `admin` 2 as well. Ex: `admin` 1 has 20 docs the 2 has only 3, and so on. Does anyone know how to help me?

Ex:

```
Admin:

id  -  name   - company
 1  -  teste  -  teste2
 2  -  teste3 -  teste4


 Docs:

 id_doc -   id_admin_doc  -   doc -      value
   1       -     1        -   doc_1   -    t
   2       -     1        -   doc_2   -    t
   3       -     1        -   doc_3   -    t
   4       -     2        -   doc_1   -    t
   5       -     2        -   doc_2   -    t
   6       -     1        -   doc_4   -    t
   7       -     2        -   doc_3   -    t
   8       -     1        -   doc_5   -    t
```

Comment: Instead, you should add a column `id` to `DOCS` that is auto-increment and use it to determine the `doc_$val`

Comment: Dude, `auto_increment` is independent for each new `id_admin_doc`, so that would not work there

Comment: `id_admin_doc` should not be `auto_increment` on `DOCS`. If it is, it should not be, as admins can have multiple docs

Comment: It will be used as an identifier, it, and as each `admin` can add a new doc at any time, how will I control it if it is not` auto_increment`?

Comment: @Derek I changed the question, see if you understand better.

Comment: The way I would setup my DB if I were you, is `ADMIN` (perfect the way you have it), and `DOCS` - `id (auto_increment)`, `admin_id (foreign key, admin)`, `value (text value of document)`

Comment: and you would use `id` of `DOC`, there should never be any reason to have more than 1 `AUTO_INCREMENT` per table, ever.

Comment: @Derek Dude, you want to settle with my client kkkkkkk , he wants it because you want it

Comment: If your client really wants it that way, you should take the index of the location from the returned array of data from the specific admin, not that hard. There's just no reason to have it stored in the DB

Comment: Better yet, this is something best left for the front-end to handle.

Comment: Really, this is a good idea kkkkk, had not even thought about it, ty